# Network connection down after installing Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015

After installing visual Studio 2015 CE with Xamarin and Android Emulator my Windows 8.1 network connection is not working anymore.

Using Device Manager I now have 4 devices:

- Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
- Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
- Realtek PCI-E GBE Family Controller #2 (which cannot start)
- Realtek PCI-E GBE Family Controller #3 (which cannot start)

I tried to uninstall all of them, the result is always the same, they all come back with the warning sign.

**UPDATE:**
After uninstalling some visual studio components my network connection is working again. Uninstalled components include:

- Windows SDK
- IIS Server
- Android Emulator